# How do you get cash without a debit card quickly?

Tags: cash

I lost my debit card and need to get cash quickly. What are some good ways of doing this? There are no bank branches near me.

Comment: What country are you in? In the UK, some banks allow "emergency withdrawals" from cash machines to cover cases like this (they give you a code that you can enter without using a card).

Comment: Again, as in your last question, you forgot to provide your country. So how shall anybody know what options there are around you when we don't know what "around you" actually is?

Comment: It may be worth calling your bank and asking. Some financial institutions have shared branching relationships with other FIs that allow their customers to do basic transactions (withdraw, deposit) at each other's branches.

Comment: How much cash? Also, if it’s for a specific use, for what? There may be alternatives to cash available.

Comment: We don't know where you live. We don't know how much cash you need. We don't know what other financial institutions you have relationships with. We don't know what "quickly" means to you. We don't know what you've already tried, and why it failed. My advice: ask your mom what to do. Your mom probably knows that information; we don't.

Comment: Downvoted as the question is too vague absent revisions/clarifications from OP

Answer (score 4):

Use Venmo, Paypal, Zelle, or similar to send money to a friend who can give you cash in exchange.

Comment: Can you buy a prepaid debit card and transfer money there using banking and routing number?

Answer (score 3):

- Some credit cards allow ATM withdrawals as cash advances.
- if you have access to your checkbook, you could also make a check out to CASH and take it to anywhere that offers check-cashing services
- You could possibly send yourself money via something like Western Union
- pawn something
- borrow some from a friend

There are also, of course, illicit ways to get cash. I won’t attempt to enumerate them here.